# DynamoDbImmutable vs DynamoDbBean

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

i am new to dynamodb sdk2.
i can find example easily.
so i made simple init project using kotlin, spring boot.

I have a question about entity annotation.
some example use DynamoDbImmutable annotation and others use DynamoDbBean annotation.

i already read [github aws-sdk-java-v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/tree/master/services-custom/dynamodb-enhanced#working-with-immutable-data-classes), but still don't understand what's the difference between them.

can anyone let me know?

Answer (score 0):

The only apparent difference I can see is that DynamoDbImmutable is used when you use Builder style class instantiation as it has a builder method, whereas DynamoDBBean does not.